# Не получаю изменений в onChange когда вставляю данные в БД

Tags: android, mvvm, room, livedata

Решил попробовать написать приложения с архитектурой mvvm. В общем не получаю изменений в onChange когда вставляю данные в бд.
Логика, которой хочу добиться:
Идем в кеш, берем данные. Потом ломимся на сервер получаем данные. Если есть изменения обновляем и кеш и ui.
Подскажите что не так делаю?

```
class PageFragment : BaseFragment() {

    private val pageName= "fly"

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        ...

        val viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(PageViewModel(activity!!.appliacation)::class.java)

        viewModel.getPages().observe(this, Observer<Page> { page ->
            adapter.contents = page!!.content

        })
        viewModel.pageName = pageName

        return view
    }
}
```

ViewModel class

```
class PageViewModel constructor(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    private var repository: Repository = Repository(application)

    private var mutablePages = MutableLiveData<Page>()
    fun getPages(): LiveData<Page> = mutablePages

    var pageName: String = ""
        set(value) {
            field = value
            loadData(value)
        }

    private fun loadData(pageName: String) {
        GlobalScope.launch {
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                mutablePages.value = repository.getPage(pageName)
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Repository class

```
class Repository(context: Context) {

private var dbRepository: DbRepository = DbRepository(context)

....

suspend fun getPage(pageName: String): Page =
            dbRepository.getPage(pageName).let { pagesMapper.dbToBusinessEntity(it) }.also {
//Берем данные с сервера и кладем их в бд
//Данные с сервера приходят и складываются в бд - нормально. По этому не буду описывать тут, как это делается.
                GlobalScope.launch { updatePage(pageName) }
            }

....

    }
```

DbRepository class

```
class DbRepository(context: Context) {

private var pagesDao: pagesDao = AppDatabase.getInstance(context).pagesDao()

....

suspend fun getpage(pageName: String): PageDb =
            GlobalScope.async { pagesDao.getPage(pageName) }.await()

....

}
```

Dao class

```
@Dao
interface PagesDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE pageName= :pageName")
    fun getPage(pageName: String): PageDb

}
```

Entity data class

```
@Entity(tableName = "pages")
data class PageDb(

        var content: List<Any>,
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
        var pageName: String

)
```

Также хотелось бы услышать критику в адрес этого кода...

Answer (score 0):

Нашел, в чём была проблема...
Чтобы LiveData уведомляли об изменении данных, метод для получения данных из бд не должен иметь ключевого слова suspend.